# setcookie not working 3

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie based on the returned value from an insert into mySQL. I know the insert has worked as I have a value for mysqli_insert_id($link). However, he cookie is the same before and after I attempt to run setcookie. Can anyone help? The code I am using is

```
echo mysqli_insert_id($link)."<br>";
print_r($_COOKIE); 
echo "<br>";
setcookie("id", mysqli_insert_id($link), time() + 60*60*24);
print_r($_COOKIE);
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: **From the manual** _setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including <html> and <head> tags as well as any whitespace._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) needs to be sent before anything is echoed out to the body of the page. For example:

```
echo 'test'; //At this point, headers are done, and the body has started
setcookie(...); //Fails
```

An alternative solution would be to use [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to buffer the output into memory before outputting to the browser. You can do something like this:

```
ob_start();
echo 'test'; //Output is captured, and stored in memory
setcookie(...); //Nothing has been output yet, so header is set properly

ob_end_flush(); //We're done storing stuff in the buffer, output it to the browser.
```

Comment: Thank you
I wasn't aware of that restriction - but no I have removed the echo & print_r it works perfectly